# How to dynamically check for role in ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity, and I want to create a `BaseController` class that can be used everywhere.

I want to declare it this way:

```
[Authorize (Roles = BaseConfig.Roles)]
public class BaseController : Controller
```

This way, I can centralize some features that need authentication and authorization, but for specific roles.

However, this does not compile and complaints that:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
> or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

If this is not possible, then how can I check roles dynamically?

Comment: How do you define BaseConfig.Roles?

Comment: You should use `Policy` instead of role for authorization.About [policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0).